# :checked does not switch icons on toggle

Tags: css

I've been playing with a checked menu which toggles on/off when it is clicked with an icon. I have not included the icons in the [CodePen example](http://codepen.io/j_mes/full/zGzJVm/) but have replaced with B for burger icon and X for close icon.

What I can't figure out is why it will not switch from B to X when it is in the checked state, as the navigation works correctly then. Here is the code below for the HTML and the CSS (with Sass).

```
<!-- nav -->
<nav class="nav" id="menu" role="navigation">

  <!-- nav toggle -->
  <label for="toggle" class="nav--btn">
    <span class="icon--burger" aria-hidden="true">B</span>
    <span class="icon--close" aria-hidden="true">X</span>
    <span class="text">MENU</span>
  </label>

  <input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
  <!-- /nav toggle -->

  <ul class="nav--toggle">
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav><!-- /nav -->
```

CSS / Sass

```
// Toggle
.nav--btn {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 2em;
  width: 100%;

  &:hover, &:focus {
    background-color: orange;
  }
}

#toggle,
.nav--toggle,
.icon--close,
#toggle:checked + .icon--burger {
  display: none;
}

#toggle:checked + .nav--toggle,
#toggle:checked + .icon--close {
  display: inline;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.text {
  /* Hide from the website but visible for screen readers */
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  height: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
}

// Navigation Menu
.nav {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;

  > ul {
    text-align: center;

    > li {
      display: block;
      float: left;
      width: 100%;

      background-color: lightgray;
      border-bottom: 2px solid darkgray;

      > a {
        display: block;
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 2em 0;
      } // end a
    } // end li
  } // end ul
} // end nav
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In CSS, `+` is an [adjacent sibling combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators):

> The adjacent sibling combinator is made of the "plus sign" (U+002B, `+`)
>   character that separates two sequences of simple selectors. The
>   elements represented by the two sequences share the same parent in the
>   document tree and the element represented by the first sequence
>   immediately precedes the element represented by the second one.

But your HTML is

```html
<label for="toggle" class="nav--btn">
  <span class="icon--burger" aria-hidden="true">B</span>
  <span class="icon--close" aria-hidden="true">X</span>
</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
```

Therefore, neither of those selectors work:

```css
#toggle:checked + .icon--burger
#toggle:checked + .nav--toggle
```

To fix it, change your HTM to

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
<label for="toggle" class="nav--btn">
  <span class="icon--burger" aria-hidden="true">B</span>
  <span class="icon--close" aria-hidden="true">X</span>
</label>
```

And your CSS to

```css
#toggle:checked ~ .nav--btn > .icon--burger {
  display: none;
}
#toggle:checked ~ .nav--toggle,
#toggle:checked ~ .nav--btn > .icon--close {
  display: block;
}
```

where `~` is the [general sibling combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#general-sibling-combinators).

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  font-size: 16px;
}
p {
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}
.wrap {
  margin: 2em auto;
  width: 80%;
}
h1 {
  border-bottom: 4px solid #ccc;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.nav--btn {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 2em;
  width: 100%;
}
.nav--btn:hover,
.nav--btn:focus {
  background-color: orange;
}
#toggle,
.nav--toggle,
.icon--close,
#toggle:checked ~ .nav--btn > .icon--burger {
  display: none;
}
#toggle:checked ~ .nav--toggle,
#toggle:checked ~ .nav--btn > .icon--close {
  display: block;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.text {
  /* Hide from the website but visible for screen readers */
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  height: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
}
.nav {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
.nav > ul {
  text-align: center;
}
.nav > ul > li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightgray;
  border-bottom: 2px solid darkgray;
}
.nav > ul > li > a {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 2em 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <h1>Menu toggle with icon switch</h1>
  <p>Imagine the B for the burger icon and X for the close icon.</p>
  <!-- nav -->
  <nav class="nav" id="menu" role="navigation">
    <!-- nav toggle -->
    <input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
    <label for="toggle" class="nav--btn">
      <span class="icon--burger" aria-hidden="true">B</span>
      <span class="icon--close" aria-hidden="true">X</span>
      <span class="text">MENU</span>
    </label>
    <!-- /nav toggle -->
    <ul class="nav--toggle">
      <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav><!-- /site-nav -->
</div><!-- /wrap -->
```

Answer (score 3):

The way you have given the `<input />` is wrong. You cannot go previous element. The icons **B** and **X** are coming before the `<input />` element. You need to rewrite the HTML like this:

**Solution**

```css
#check {display: none;}
label {display: inline-block; cursor: pointer; background: #ccf; padding: 10px;}
#check:checked + .menu .button-click .b,
#check + .menu .menu-items,
#check + .menu .button-click .x {display: none;}
#check:checked + .menu .button-click .x,
#check:checked + .menu .menu-items {display: block;}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="check" />
<div class="menu">
  <label class="button-click" for="check">
    <span class="b">B</span>
    <span class="x">X</span>
  </label>
  <ul class="menu-items">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Reason:**

Sibling selectors do not work this way:

```css
#toggle:checked + .icon--burger
#toggle:checked + .nav--toggle
```